# Javascript - Get text via ajax and display in a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

**Use Case:** I want to represent some text with ellipsis (e.g. My name is ...) in a HTML LINK/ anchor, where the text is fetched by an ajax call.

Whenever the user clicks the link, I load the text completely in a modal dialog box) by making the same ajax call used to fetch the text.

Here is the code:

```
"aoColumns": [
    <Some code for columns>

    {"mData": "id", sWidth:"180px","mRender": function ( data, type, full )  {
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(full));
    JSRoutes.com.app.controllers.File.getContent(obj["fileId"]).ajax({
         data: {},
         success: function(data) {
         console.log("This is the data I want to represent in ellipsis: " + data);
    }
    });

    return "<a>" + <HOW TO PUT CONTENT (data) HERE> +"</a>";
]
```

Problem: **How to make the ajax call to fetch file content and provide the anchor element's text at the same time.** Because by the time we 'return', the ajax call might not have finished.

I might not have been successful in explaining the question clearly, so comments and questions are welcome to improve the question.

Comment: you need to write the `return "<a>..."` inside the success function!

Comment: @AminJafari: Let me try that and I'll update this post. Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first letter 'a' in 'ajax' stands for **async**, means you cannot get the result directly, but the result will be provided to your callback function later.

In your example:

```
JSRoutes....ajax({
    success: function(data){
                 // async callback
             }
});
```

This `success` function is which will be executed after the ajax returns.

So that you should return an empty `<a>` element first, and fill the content later in the callback.

example:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
JSRoutes......ajax({
    success: function(data){
                 a.textContent = data;
             }
});
return a;
```

Comment: Thanks! I do understand 'A'JAX. That's why the question. Can you please modify your answer to include document.createElement() in jquery and attach an onClick callback as well? I am pretty new to javascript and jquery, and dont know how to do it.

Comment: Create element with `var a = $('<a></a>');`, set content with `a.text(data);`, and bind the callback with `a.on('click', function(){/*callback*/});`. You'd better have a look at the [jquery api reference](http://api.jquery.com) to find functions you want.

Comment: I checked your answer and it doesn't seem to work. Reason: the function can just return strings to the dataTables render property. Is there a way to return a html anchor string without using javscript createElement?

Comment: You have to provide a method to modify the content **later**, and call that in the ajax callback. There is no way to directly return the result as you described, because that's the **synchronous** way.

Comment: I ended up using unique ids to modify anchor's text in ajax callback. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I went with using the element id to modify the text later in the ajax function success callback.

As the file Ids are unique, I can provide unique HTML anchor ids.

```
"aoColumns": [
    <Some code for columns>

    {"mData": "id", sWidth:"180px","mRender": function ( data, type, full )  {
        var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(full));
        JSRoutes.com.app.controllers.File.getContent(obj["fileId"]).ajax({
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            var linkText = "";
            var n = 70;
            if (data.length > n) {
                linkText = data.substr(0,n) + " ...";
            } else {
                linkText = data;
            }
            $( '#file_'+obj["fileId"]).text(linkText);
        }
        });

      return "<a> id=file_" + obj["fileId"] + ">" + "This will be loaded soon" +"</a>";
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX are asynchronous. so if you want to finish the some task first and calling the second function only after the completion of the first one than you have to write it in Javascript function instead of calling it in jQuery.